# XmlPullParserException exception when parsing feed on Android

Tags: android, rss

I'm getting an `XmlPullParserException` exception when parsing feed on Android using the `com.einmalfel.earl` parsing library (https://github.com/einmalfel/Earl)

`E/Error:(): Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:50 in java.io.StringReader@43240)`

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of researching and testing, I found this is caused by a http to https redirect.

My solution was to catch this exception, see if the URL is `http` and reattempt using `https`. In all cases this has worked.